# IIS, Spring.Net WCF Http Session Management

Tags: wcf, session, iis, spring.net, session-timeout

I'm building a (thin)client-server application with IIS as server using Spring.Net as main technology and a thin WPF presentation client comunicating via WCF to the server (we plan a Web version of the client in the future)
When I login I create an http session cookie to have a statefull session like a web browser and I acquire a license from the Server.
When I logout or if the IIS session times out (because the client crashed or the user could not logout correctly) I need to:

- release the license
- free all the session scoped objects from the server RAM.

So I need to implement this two things:

- A hook to the EndSession event to handle timeout and crashes
- A logoff procedure which communicates the End of the session to IIS after freeing the license.

I've looked online but didn't find a clear example on how to do this two way session management. If you could help me and provide some xml configuration examples for IIS, Spring.Net would be greatly appreciated

FYI this are the main WCF and WEB configuration present in my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBinding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="31457280" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="31457280" maxArrayLength="31457280" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="wcfService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Nemsys.SMF.Service.Tunnel.IWCFService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  <sessionState timeout="60" />

  <!-- needed by Spring.Net on IIS 7.0 -->
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<!-- needed by Spring.Net on IIS 7.0 -->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules>
    <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="SpringPageHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web" />
    <add name="SpringContextMonitor" verb="*" path="ContextMonitor.ashx" type="Spring.Web.Support.ContextMonitor, Spring.Web" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**Actually I've managed to correctly free the resources on Logout or Http Session expiration by implementing IDisposable in the BLL class which manages the user session and is called before disposing the object. 
The only thing that I don't know how to do is:
when the user clicks the logout button after freeing the license I need to destroy the http Session letting IIS and Spring collect and free all the session resources they allocated.**

Comment: Imho this is not spring.net related. If you are on IIS and use an asp.net Session you can create a global.asax and use `protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)` to cleanup.

Comment: According to your update `SessionState.Abandon();` is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:
Having configured Spring to listen to IIS events in the Logout method of my session use case I call

```
public void Logout()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }
```

This as suggested by Andreas triggers the end session event which tells Spring that all the session scoped object can be garbage collected.
My use case which manages the user session also implements the IDisposable interface and the Dispose() method is called before freeing the object.
In this method I contact a License use case (which is a singleton) asking him to free the license.

Comment: This works in my debug environment but when trying it in production the Dispose() method isn't invoked